# Is there a work-a-round to serializing some Microsoft Graph Entities with interfaces like Domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I wanted to generate a test program to execute against our client tenants to verify we could handle all the data our new Microsoft graph app collects. My plan was to serialize the data  using
`XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));`

It failed on the first entity I tried, Microsoft.Graph.Domain ( in this case with the error
`Cannot serialize member Microsoft.Graph.Entity.AdditionalData of type  ... because it is an interface.`

A search on stack overflow found suggestions to decorate the problematic class property with XmlIgnore so XmlSerializer will ignore it, others recommended implementing a new IXmlSerializer. One post seemed to propose using serializing to XAML.

Open to a better way to collect real customer data which I can import into my unit tests? As a developer I do not have direct access to customer accounts.

Does anyone have other suggestions on how to serialize Microsoft Graph Entities.

Comment: It looks like Json will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my XmlSerializer with a Json one.

```
public void SerializeObjectsToJson<T>(List<T> serializableObjects)
{
        var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableObjects);
} 

public List<T> DeSerializeObjectsFromXml<T>()
{
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fqpathname, Encoding.UTF8);
        var jsonStr = textReader.ReadToEnd();
        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(jsonStr);
}
```

This all seems to work with Domain, User, SubscribedSkus, Organization, etc.